# Scatter Chart settings in google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, pygooglechart

[Code for Mchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCepg.jpg)how to set min and max values for the horizontal scale, in script

I've tried with and without varible for hAxis. in the code example it is hard coded in. Doesn't change the value of the scale no matter what.

Expect the vAxis and the hAxis to have the values I assign when they are passed in the code.[Output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inTRx.jpg)

[Using chart settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb3pG.jpg)

Comment: .setOption('vAxes.0.viewWindow.max', Maxy)
  .setOption('vAxes.0.viewWindow.min', Miny)
  .setOption('hAxes.0.viewWindow.max',38)
  .setOption('hAxes.0.viewWindow.min',-38)
  .setOption('trendlines.0.type', 'linear')
  .setPosition(1, 1, 24, 225)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
};

Comment: function ChartM() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  app.getRange('Y4').activate();
  var sheet = app.getActiveSheet();
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  var Mtitle = sheet.getRange('V1').getValue();
  var Miny = sheet.getRange('w8').getValue();
  var Maxy = sheet.getRange('w9').getValue();
  //Logger.log(Maxy);
  //Logger.log(Miny);

Comment: chart = sheet.newChart()
   .asScatterChart()
  .addRange(app.getRange('Y1:Z3'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)

Comment: .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', Mtitle)
  .setXAxisTitle('Value of x')
  .setYAxisTitle('Value of y')

Comment: Sorry no matter what I tried couldn't get the code in question , there was always an error. Looks like code but not formatted add 4 spaces . Used Ctrl K still didn't work

Comment: You need to figure out how to get the code into the question - it's impossible to decipher when it's buried in the comments without formatting. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Josh I added it to a picture.